# What ruby languaje is used by bluepill cookbook

Tags: service, chef-infra, chef-recipe, bluepill

I have some doubts about a specific attribute of bluepill cookbook.

```
default["bluepill"]["bin"] = "#{node['languages']['ruby']['bin_dir']}/bluepill
```

Where and when is defined this value?

I want to use the bluepill as a system's gem and not as a chef's gem, What values or options I have for this attribute:

```
default["bluepill"]["bin"] = ?????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value comes from [Ohai](https://github.com/opscode/ohai), which is a tool used by Chef to get the JSON representation of important system information (like where a Ruby lives or what users are present on a system).

That attribute may be changed to any value, but it must point to a Ruby that exists on the system. Note: that attribute does not install Ruby - it just tells Bluepill where to find Ruby.

Comment: But, Why if I have a ruby on my system the value is redirected to /opt/chef/.... and not to the vagrant_ruby folder in my case?? Sorry for asking a lot !!

Comment: Because Ohai prefer's Chef's ruby